# Setting random seed in python disturbs multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, python-2.x, python-multiprocessing

I've observed that setting a random seed before using multiprocessing in python causes strange behaviour.

In python 3.5.2, only 2 or 3 cores are used with a low percentage of used CPU.
In python 2.7.13, all requested cores are used at 100%, but the code seems to never finish. When I remove the initialization of the random seed, the parallelization works fine.

This happens even though there is not an explicit use of random in the parallelized function. I now assume the seed is shared among processes and that prevents the smooth running of multiprocessing, but can someone provide the correct answer?

---

I've run the code on Linux and here is a minimal code example :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed = 2018

NB_CPUS = 4

def test(x):
    return x**2

pool = Pool(NB_CPUS)
args = [np.random.rand() for _ in range(100000)]

results = pool.map(test, args)

pool.terminate()
results[-5:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit late with an answer, but you're breaking things by setting the [`random.seed` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) to an `int`.  You should instead be doing:

```
random.seed(2018)
```

the last few lines of traceback provide the context that should have made this obvious:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 125, in __init__
    random.seed()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

this causes `Pool` to keep trying to create new worker processes, but because this happens every time no forward progress can be made.

The behind this is that `multiprocessing` knows it should re-seed the random module when forking so that child processes don't share the same RNG state.  To do this it tries to call the `random.seed` function, but you've set it to an `int` which isn't callable --- hence the error!

Another issue related to this is that `multiprocessing` doesn't know to re-seed the NumPy RNG, so the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

def test(i):
    print(i, np.random.rand())

with Pool(4) as pool:
    pool.map(test, range(4))
```

will cause each worker to print the same value.  [This issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9650) has been known for a while, but is still open.  You can work around this by using a worker `initializer`, e.g:

```
def initfn():
    np.random.seed()

with Pool(4, initializer=initfn) as pool:
    pool.map(test, range(4))
```

will now cause the above `test` function to print different  values.  Note that you could even use `Pool(4, initializer=np.random.seed)` if you're not doing any other work level initialization.